# How to modify just one file when repackaging an archive?

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to take a non-Bazel produced zipfile, modify some files in it, keeping most of them alone, and then ultimately produce a new tarball with the ~original content (plus my modifications)

I'm having trouble specifying my rules in a clean way and it'd be great if there was a suggestion on how to do it.

I'm importing the original zip file via the 'new_http_archive' WORKSPACE rule. This works pretty well. I put the build file in a package one level under the root. Let's call this 'foo_repackage'.

In foo_repackage/BUILD.root_archive:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

filegroup(
    name = "all_files",
    srcs = glob(
        ["**"],
        exclude = ["*", "share/doc/api/**"]
    ),
)
```

The bigger issue is in the foo_repackage/BUILD file, I'd like to take all of the files out of the all_files group above, **except** for a few of them that I will modify. I can't see how to do this easily. It seems like every file that I want to modify I should exclude from the above glob and make a new rule that specifies that file. This means that I have to keep modifying the global all_files exclude rule.

If I could create a new filegroup that was all of the above files with some files excluded, that'd be ideal.

I should mention that the last step is of course to use pkg_tar to repackage the result - this is in foo_repackage/BUILD

```
pkg_tar(
    name = "OutputTarball",
    files = ["@root_archive//:all_files"],
    deps = [":layers_of_modified_files"],
    strip_prefix = "/../root_archive",
)
```

Does anyone have a better way to do this?

Thanks, Sean

Comment: This seems reasonable to me. What's your main concern here? That the exclude list will become very long?

You might run into a problem where you are trying to generate files with the same name as ones that exist on the filesystem (from the zip). Bazel won't like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use a variable like:

```
MODIFIABLE_FILES = [
    "some/file",
    "another/file",
    ...
]

filegroup(
    name = "static-files",
    srcs = glob(["**"], exclude = MODIFIABLE_FILES)
)

filegroup(
    name = "modifiable-files",
    srcs = MODIFIABLE_FILES,
)
```

Then the list of static files and modifiable files will be kept in sync and you'll get a build error if you accidentally specify a non-existent modifiable file.

Comment: This is perfect. I didn't think of the variable solution - it makes maintenance easy, and in particular, it makes it unlikely that one will make an error in modifying one of the static files, because they won't be in the second filegroup.